# Retrieve S3 bucket name from terraform module

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am using the following module to create cloudfront with s3 bucket:

```
module "cloudfront" {
              source = /modules/cloudfront-w-s3/aws
        ......
        }
```

Now my questions is. How I can retrieve the s3 bucket or arn from this module and use it as output?

Answer (score 0):

What does the child module (the one you are calling) look like in its main.tf?

If you are using this [link](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket) for the S3 resource then in your child module create an `outputs.tf` file. Create an output with whatever name you want, `s3_arn` as an example, with a value of `aws_s3_bucket.<RESOURCE_NAME>.arn`.

In your root module create an outputs.tf and use the same code above but for the value use `module.<MODULE_NAME>.s3_arn`. In your `main.tf` for the parent module you should be able to access that output using the syntax of `module.<MODULE_NAME>.s3_arn`.